# Updating post is not saving in the database

Tags: django, django-views

hello i'm a beginner to django, i made an edit button where i can edit a post, but the problem is it's not saving in the database[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lozFz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEtVa.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfr8g.png)

i tried everything i could went to youtube but nothing

Comment: Put code of Post Model in Question

Comment: Try using class based views. They are much simpler, and you don't have to deal with this headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use class based views. They are much simpler and less headache. This is how they work. More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/)

In your urls you have to add .as_view()

```
from .views import UpdateView
path('post/<pk>/update', UpdatePost.as_view()),
```

in views.py

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
class UpdatePost(UpdateView):
    template_name = "update_post.html"
    model = Post
    form = YourForm() or Fields = ["title", "content", "whatever you named them in your models"]
    success_url ="/"
```